# Why django class based View (DetailView) only works with a specific variable names

Tags: python, django, django-views

My following question is to understand why the variable `template_name`, for example with the class `DetailView`, only works with exactly that variable name.

For example in views.py:

```py
    from django.views.generic import DetailView

        # /appPruebaDos/detailView/<int:pk>
        class DetailViewObject(DetailView):
            model = Articulo
            template_name = "plantillaDetailView.html" # varible fijado del tipo DetailView
```

Why I can't use other variable like(this don't work):

```py
    # /appPruebaDos/detailView/<int:pk>
    class DetailViewObject(DetailView):
        model = Articulo
        templateName = "plantillaDetailView.html" # varible fijado del tipo DetailView
```

I think template_name field is defined in the DetailView dependencies, but how and where is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good practise to follow the standard conventions of a language. In Python, the standard identifier naming convention is [Snake Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (Example: template_name).

Secondly, the reason why `templateName` doesn't work and `template_name` does, is because the class you inherited (`DetailView`) looks for an attribute named `template_name` in your class.

You can see the way Django tries to find `template_name` in Django's Github repository. 
Here's the [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5b884d45ac5b76234eca614d90c83b347294c332/django/views/generic/base.py#L144) to the base class of Django's views which implements a function called `get_template_names()`.

Comment: Python lets you name variables whatever you want (with exceptions for reserved words), but in this case we're using a variable that someone else named. That's how I look at it.